# flutter firestore image: How to display image through url which is in firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the images url in console and it is printing in it, but I am not able to display the image inside the container. This is the complete code with Dot indicators and delete button. This code works fine as I'm able to display the image if I get them direct through cloud storage but not able to get it through firestore which is stored in image collection in array with index  uploaded as map. But url gets print in console as I have mentioned in code below. pls check it out. PS: second and third page may or may be not related here with query but it might help someone who are trying to get dot indicators or delete button or full image view as this code works fine if I get the images direct through cloud storage.Thanks for your time.[image]

```
   class PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO extends StatefulWidget{


 int currentIndex;
 List<String> imageList;


 PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO({Key key,@required this.imageList,@required this.currentIndex})
  :super(key:key);

 @override
 _PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO createState() => _PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO();
  }

 class _PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO extends State<PortfolioGallarySubPageTWO>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


 final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

 final _stoarge = FirebaseStorage.instance;
 final CollectionReference _reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
  "users");
 final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 final FirebaseFirestore fb = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


 List<File> _images = [];
 List<String> imageList = [];
 int currentIndex;



  @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
  _getImagesOK();
  
  }

   @override
   void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
   }


    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
       actions: [
         ElevatedButton(
           child: Text("DONE", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
           onPressed: () {
          _uploadImages();
        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 15.0, 25.0, 10.0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Container(
    width: _maxScreenWidth,
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [

              
              Container(

                height: 160.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0,horizontal: 15.0),

                child: CustomScrollView(
                 
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),


                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverPadding(

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      sliver:
                      _buildContentTWO(imageList),

                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
   }



    _getImagesOK() async {
    DocumentSnapshot firebaseDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      "users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();

     List imageList = firebaseDoc.data()['images'];

     print(imageList[0]);

     String _u = await imageList.toString();


    imageList.add(_u);
    setState(() {
      print(imageList.length);
     print(imageList);
      });
    }


    SliverGrid _buildContentTWO(List<String> imageList) {
    return SliverGrid(

      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  ),
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(

        (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return PortfolioGalleryImageWidgetTWO(imageList: imageList[index],
        onImageTap: () =>
            Navigator.push(context,
              _createGalleryDetail(imageList, index),
            ),
      );
    },
    childCount: imageList.length,
  ),

);
 }

    MaterialPageRoute _createGalleryDetail(List<String> imageList, int index) {
   return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
      PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO(
        imageList: imageList,
         currentIndex: index,
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

The second page: The page is for DOT indicators and to get index and displayed on image

```
   class PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO extends StatefulWidget{
   final List<String> imageList;
   final int currentIndex;

   PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO({Key key, @required this.imageList,@required this.currentIndex})
  : super(key: key);

   @override
  _PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO createState() => _PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO();
}

   class _PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO extends State<PortfolioGalleryDetailPageTWO>{
    int _currentIndex;
   PageController _pageController;

    @override
    void initState(){
   super.initState();
    _currentIndex = widget.currentIndex;
   _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentIndex);
    }

   final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

   @override
   Widget build (BuildContext context){

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.black,),
  body: _buildContent(),
);
  }

  Widget _buildContent(){

return Stack(
  children: [
    _buildPhotoViewGallery(),
    _buildIndicator(),
    _deleteImage(),
  ],
);
 }

   Widget _deleteImage(){
   return Positioned(
     right: -2,
   top: -9,
  child: new Deletebtn(),
);
   }



     Widget _buildIndicator(){
    return Positioned(
    bottom: 2.0,
  left: 2.0,
  right: 2.0,
  // child: _buildDot(),
  child: _buildDottedIndicator(),
);
  }

  Row _buildDottedIndicator(){
  return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: widget.imageList.map<Widget>((String imageList) => _buildDot(imageList)).toList(),
);
  }

  Container _buildDot(String imageList){
return Container(

  width: 5,
  height: 5,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 2.0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: _currentIndex == widget.imageList.indexOf(imageList) ? Colors.red : Colors.white,

      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(2.5),
      boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.red,
            blurRadius: 10.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 1.0))
      ]),

);
  }


  PhotoViewGallery _buildPhotoViewGallery(){
  return PhotoViewGallery.builder(
  itemCount: widget.imageList.length,
  builder: (BuildContext context,int index){
    return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
      imageProvider: NetworkImage(widget.imageList[index]),
      minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
      maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 1.8,
    );
  },
  scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  pageController: _pageController,
  onPageChanged: (int index){
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  },
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
);
  }



    }

 class Deletebtn extends StatelessWidget{
 final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context ) {
return new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
      color: const Color(0xFF227770),
      size: 35,
    ),
    onPressed: () async {
      var val =[];

      var userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update({ "images" : FieldValue.arrayRemove(val)}).then((_) {
        print("deleted");
      });
    },
  ),
);
  }


 }
```

The third page: This is for the how image look inside the container and on image tap it gives full screen image view.

```
class PortfolioGalleryImageWidgetTWO extends StatelessWidget{
final String imageList;
final VoidCallback onImageTap;

const PortfolioGalleryImageWidgetTWO({Key key,@required this.imageList, @required this.onImageTap})
  :super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow:[
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(2, 2),
        spreadRadius: 2,
        blurRadius: 5,
      ),
    ],
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),

  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Ink.image(image: NetworkImage(imageList),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: InkWell(onTap: onImageTap),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why you are using Firestore to store URL .. I recommended to use Firebase Storage and their is method called `getDownloadURL()` which will give you URL which you can preview in the Container if this URL for User so store then in FirebaseAuth as URL which called PhotoURL and preview also in container .. I am sorry I can not show you example beacause I am not Flutter Dev but Javascript Dev as I done that in JS .. Thanks

Comment: Please share what you are getting now, and how you would like the result to be. The code snippets posted cause a bit of confusion, as it's hard to tell where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, through _getImagesOK function I am getting the url array list as you can see I am printing it in console but in the container widget where I am try to getting them in _buildContentTWO(imageList), on first page I am not able to display it and when I get them directly through cloud storage it displays fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this first:

```
  _getImagesOK() async {
    DocumentSnapshot firebaseDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      "users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();
    List<String> imageListTemp =[];
     for(var item in firebaseDoc.data()['images']){
      imageListTemp.add(item); 
     }
   
    setState(() {
      imageList=imageListTemp;
      print(imageList.length);
     print(imageList);
      });
    }
```

Comment: ERROR: 1).Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'  2)Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
3). Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0

Comment: RED line error under.addAll(imageListTemp) The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<String>'.

Comment: can I share my screen with you on any desk? If that's not too much to ask.

Comment: changed answer again, sure thing, send me the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231801/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-huthaifa-muayyad).